# 'Search:' parameter exclusion problems

Tags: parameters

I am trying to exclude entries that either have no value or a value of "0" in a field, but am running into problems with the 'search:' parameter.

```
search:product_inventory="not IS_EMPTY"
```

works and excludes all entries that have no value in that field.

As I also want to exclude fields with the value of zero, I changed it to:

```
search:product_inventory="not IS_EMPTY|0"
```

This threw this error:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'wd.field_id_8NOT' in 'where clause'

SELECT DISTINCT(t.entry_id) FROM exp_channel_titles AS t LEFT JOIN exp_channels ON t.channel_id = exp_channels.channel_id LEFT JOIN exp_channel_data AS wd ON wd.entry_id = t.entry_id LEFT JOIN exp_members AS m ON m.member_id = t.author_id INNER JOIN exp_category_posts ON t.entry_id = exp_category_posts.entry_id INNER JOIN exp_categories ON exp_category_posts.cat_id = exp_categories.cat_id WHERE t.entry_id !='' AND t.site_id IN ('1') AND t.entry_date < 1358591770 AND (t.expiration_date = 0 OR t.expiration_date > 1358591770) AND t.channel_id = '2' AND exp_categories.cat_id = '68' AND t.status = 'open' AND ( (wd.site_id=1 AND wd.field_id_8!="") AND (wd.site_id=1 AND wd.field_id_8NOT LIKE "%0%") )

Filename: modules/channel/mod.channel.php

Line Number: 2660
```

Using:

```
search:product_inventory="not 0|IS_EMPTY"
```

throws the same error.

I then tried:

```
search:product_inventory="= not 0"
```

which successfully excluded the entries with a '0' in that field.

I changed this to:

```
search:product_inventory="= not 0|IS_EMPTY"
```

but this time the 'IS_EMPTY' is being completely ignored and all entries that have no value in that field are still returned.

How can I successfully exclude entries that have no value or a value of '0' in that field?

I am running EE v.2.5.3.

Comment: I've run some tests on a 2.5.5 installation and can't replicate your problem - this works ok for me: `search:product_inventory="not IS_EMPTY|0"` I couldn't find anything in the changelog that might indicate that it's a 2.5.3 bug, but may be worth upgrading all the same.

Comment: Thanks for checking this - good to know this isn't an issue in later versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
search:product_inventory="=not 0|IS_EMPTY"
```

The key is the equals sign immediately preceding not, and IS_EMPTY at the end (the order seems important for some reason)